# Login into website without WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, browser, webrequest

I would like to check if there are any new massages on a website?

I've tried to use webBrowser to login but then I can not access HTML code, also tried HTMAgilityPack but can not login via WebRequest.Create"LINK" nor with RequestWebData"LINK".

Is it possible to access HTML code for parsing with WebBrowser or to login with RequestWebData without webBrowser?

Site is "http://mojekrpice.rs/login" and this is what I was using to access website:

```
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "username")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "pass")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("remember").SetAttribute("checked", "0")

    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "username" & "{TAB}" & "password" & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{ENTER}")
```

Or

```
Dim strResult As String = RequestWebData("http://mojekrpice.rs/kupovina")
Dim TestString As String = strResult
Dim TestArray() As String = Split(TestString)
Label1.Text = strResult
```

With second one I can not login.

Comment: Check with fiddler(http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) how the login request looks from browser, then re-create same request with HttpWebRequest(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use HttpWebRequest for that.

Basically, it's using webbrowser in code, you don't even need to have it in form.

Explanation & tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Wzel-g1U54